# Excel data extraction for specific condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dashboard

I have my data as mentioned in the below image:

From column A to H is my input field.

[image]

I want to automate my data, in such a way that whenever I continuing inserting the data below this, I should get only "CC" (column H) and the data adjacent to it should come in the another subsheet.

Example (output) as mentioned in image below:

[image]

Comment: You are going to have headaches working with Excel 2010. Are you willing to use VBA?

Comment: @user11222393, sorry it is not excel 2010. I am using version 2019, but got selected excel 2010 mistakenly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your data to table (*Insert*->*Table*) so it expands automatically when you add new row and use something like this:

`=Table2[#Headers]` in `G1` to get table headers.

`=FILTER(Table2,Table2[Data5]="a")` in `G2` to get filtered data.

Result:

[image]

Or do not make it a table and use some kind of placeholder for possible max row:

```
=FILTER(A2:E1000,E2:E1000="a")
```

[image]